# Laravel - отношения morphedByMany и вывод с постраничной навигацией

Tags: laravel, pagination, laravel-5.8

По документации создал полиморфные связи между page/tag и image/tag. Данные добавляются и все выводится.

Сейчас хочу сделать вывод всех изображений по тегу, но их в теории может быть не одна сотня. Как в этом случае не выдавать пользователю лишние данные и таким образом снизить нагрузку на сервер?

Единственное, что приходит в голову - пагинация, но поискав на просторах интернета ничего подобного не нашел.

**Часть модели тегов**:

```
public function pages()
{
  return $this->morphedByMany('App\Page', 'taggable');
}
```

**Контроллер**:

```
public function index($tag)
{
  $tag_info = Tag::where('tag_name', $tag)->get();
  $pages = [];morphedByMany
  foreach ($tag_info as $item_tag) {
    $pages = $item_tag->pages;
  }
  return view('main.tag', ['pages'=>$pages, 'tag'=>$tag]);
}
```

Подозреваю, что я двигаюсь в неправильном направлении.

Может будет другое предложение?

Думал в сторону API и AJAX, но ведь на стороне сервера в логике при этом ничего не изменится или я не прав?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> foreach ($tag_info as $item_tag) {
>   $pages = $item_tag->pages;
> }
> ```

Таким образом вы перезаписываете значение переменной при каждой итерации. Видимо вы просто ошиблись, нужно: `$pages[] = $item_tag->pages;`.

---

> Может будет другое предложение?

Как-то так можно организовать вывод сущности, например, `Article`.

**Маршрут**:

```
Route::get('articles/tags/{tag}', 'ArticlesController@tag')->name('articles.by_tag');
```

**Контроллер записей**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Tag;
use App\Article;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ArticlesController extends Controller
{
  // ... остальной код.

  public function tag(Tag $tag)
  {
    $articles = $tag->articles()
      ->with([
        // ... остальной код.
        // 'user:users.id,users.name,users.email,users.avatar',
      ])
      ->withCount([
        // ... остальной код.
      ])
      ->latest()
      ->paginate(15);

    return view('articles.by_tag', compact('articles', 'tag'));
  }
}
```

---

> Думал в сторону API и AJAX, но ведь ... ничего не изменится ...

Изменится [многое](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-resources#resource-collections), так как при создании API приложения в контроллерах будет обращение не к моделям, а к ресурсам и коллекциям ресурсов.